# Custom Renderer to Change Icon Position on NavigationBar Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image]I already create Custom Renderer to add Logo in my Navigation Bar but the problem is The Logo is on the left side of the Title, what I want is the Logo will be on the Right Side of the Title here is my Custom Renderer to do that

```
  protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var bar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)typeof(NavigationPageRenderer)
                    .GetField("_toolbar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .GetValue(this);
            //  bar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_myvalue);

            bar.SetLogo(Resource.Drawable.ic_myvalue);


        }
```

any suggestions to do that? or can we do that?  thanks

and here is my CustomToolbar.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageViewToolbar"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_myvalue"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20px"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Why don't you change the position in the `Toolbar.axml` layout?

Comment: @JoeLv do you think we can change that from Toolbar.axml ? because im using Xamarin Forms here, and once i tried to change the size of Toolbar by Change it directly in Toolbar.axml but nothing changed when i deploy the app

Comment: So, have you tried it? Are you using PCL?

Comment: yes im using PCL and already tried to change the Toolbar.axml to change the toolbar size and color so i assume the result will be same if i tried to change poistion from Toolbar.axml

Comment: [Here is a demo, you can download it and change the position in the  `Toolbar.axml`](https://github.com/AndiAn94/ToolbarTest), I test it in this demo just now, it's ok. You can compare it with you.

Comment: Please leave me a message after you test it.

Comment: @JoeLv hei what is this Base64 for ? is that a code for an image ?

Comment: Yes, it is not important, you just need change the `Toolbar.axml` and test it and compare it with you.

Comment: and in your CustomToolBar.axml in imageview tag there is no src, so i assume if that code is to set the image. So should i add src in imageview and just igonre the Base64

Comment: Yes, add src in imageview and put a textview

Comment: Hi, you just need change the position in your `Toolbar.axml`, I have tested it just now. If you need I will post an answer.

Comment: yea the logo already shows up, now i just need to move it to the right . CMIW is this the right code to move it to right   android:layout_marginLeft="20px" ?

Comment: Can you give me a capture of your solution?

Comment: By `CMIW`, what is it?

Comment: i update my question, CMIW is correct me if im wrong i already add margin left but nothing chanage suggestion please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:text="Title"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewToolbar"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: i want to make the image to move to be little bit right, what property to do that because in Xamarin.Forms ussually im using Margin to do that, what property to do that in Xamarin.Android ?

Comment: It is the same, `android:layout_marginLeft="20px"`

Comment: Maybe `20px` too little? try `20dp` to see it

Comment: ok thanks for you answer its very helpfull for me, im using  this android:layout_gravity="center"  to make my logo in center .

Comment: maybe it move but its move verry small ?

Comment: Just try `100px`, `200px`, but I don't suggest you use `px`, I only use `px `on text's size, I usually use `dp`.

Comment: If it not work, you can add a `View` tag to achieve your goal.